# How can I debug/fix a crash with the Worklight 6.2 CLI installer?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-cli

I've downloaded a copy of the Worklight CLI installer from here, specifically [the installer for 6.2.0.1](http://public.dhe.ibm.com/ibmdl/export/pub/software/products/en/MobileFirstPlatform/worklight_cli_installer_6.2.0.1.zip) (I'm aware this isn't current, I need an older version to debug a specific problem). I am attempting to install it on OS X Mountain Lion (10.9).

However, I seem to be having problems installing it. When I unzip the installer, I get an `install_mac.app/` directory. I open this with `open install_mac.app` from the Terminal. However, when I've clicked the button to enter the administrator password (which is accepted), the installer then shows this screen for about 5 seconds, then disappears completely (is no longer running). It appears that at this point it has crashed (although there is no stack trace or similar in the terminal).

[image]

How can I debug/fix the installer? Alternatively, is there a way to manually install the CLI?

My `$JAVA_HOME` is set to `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_51.jdk/Contents/Home`. `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_51.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java -version` gives:

```
java version "1.7.0_51"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_51-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.51-b03, mixed mode)
```

Comment: I have tested the installer on my Mac and it works fine, I noticed that the WL command line version is 6.2.0.00 and not 6.2.0.1, also can you share the JAVA_HOME path?

Comment: Hussam, it is 6.2.0.00 once the `.zip` is expanded, yes. I think that is a mistake in packaging, I would assume.

Comment: Hussam, thanks, edited my Java details into the question.

Comment: I have the same configuration except the OS version(mine is the latest one), I tested the installer again on our central Mac machine and also was successful. Can you test an updated WL cli installer like MFP 7 and see if you are able to download it (https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/install/#clui)?

Comment: Hussam, yep, 6.3 and 7.0 work fine. It's only 6.2 I have this problem with. Is there any way to turn logging/debug on for the install wizard?

Answer (score 0):

On OS X the CLI installer does not provide the ability to install from command line.

However what you could do is to manually extract it instead of using the installer, and in order to compensate on the actions that the installer is doing (node registration, PATH handling), put the extracted content at the same location of the currently installed CLI. Replace it.

The above .zip is inside the "resources" folder, next to the OS X/Windows/Linux installer files.